# Is MonthName a reserved word in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reserved-words

I am creating a table that has a column called MonthName. When I defined this column the word "MonthName" showed up in blue like it was a reserved word. So I tried to look it up.

I cannot find it in Books Online or on Microsoft's site or even on our own SO.

I tried sp_help "monthname" and the reply was "The Object 'monthname' does not exists in database 'yourdb' or is invalid for this operation.

Here is the code

```
Create Table AtlasDataWarehouseReports.Calendar
(
    CalendarId              Integer NOT NULL,
    DateValue               Date    NOT NULL,
    DayOfTheWeek            Integer NOT NULL,
    NameOfDay               VarChar (10) NOT NULL,
    MonthNumber             Integer NOT NULL,
    MonthName               VarChar (10) NOT NULL,  
    CalendarQuarter         Integer NOT NULL,   
    NameOfCalendarQuarter   VarChar (20) NOT NULL,
    FinancialQuarter        Integer NOT NULL,   
    NameOfFinancialQuarter  VarChar (20) NOT NULL,  
    CalendarYear            Integer NOT NULL,
    FinancialYear           Integer NOT NULL,
    WeekOfYear              Integer NOT NULL,
    JulianDay               Integer NOT NULL,
    USAIsBankHoliday        Bit     NOT NULL,
    USADayName              VarChar (100) NULL,
)
```

```
SQL Server Version Info
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.2531.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 10.0.1600.22
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 3.85.1132
Microsoft MSXML 2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.3082
Operating System 5.1.2600
```

What, pray, is MonthName in SQL 2008?

Comment: The real question is why are you modelling columns for information you can get using SQL Server date functions?  The calendar table should hold the date as a DateTime data type; if you want the info you listed, create a view that uses the SQL Server date functions.

Comment: He's doing it for analysis services.

Comment: Maybe he is doing it becasue it is faster to convert once when the data is moved to the warehouse than to run a function every time you query the data. Warehouses are all about select speed and are often denormalized.

Comment: I am doing it for data warehousing. I want to avoid as many run time computations as I can.

Answer (score 1):

as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143507.aspx) MonthName doesn't appear to be to be a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

Have you or anyone in your team written a function MonthName already?

<strike>As per [this](http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/12334/69412.aspx), SQL 2005 has introduced MonthName function, it seems.</strike>

EDIT: I think this could have been added to support SQL Reporting Services.

EDIT2: I dont have SQL management studio but try typing in any of the Reporting Services function names to see if they are highlighted in blue.

Comment: You are incorrect.  There is no MonthName function in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Its not me who is saying. Some guys on other forum discussing the same thing.

Comment: My apologies. That is what I assumed

Answer (score 0):

MONTHNAME is a reserved word in MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

What IDE are you using that made the word show up as blue?

Comment: It happens in SQL Server Management Studio (even 2005)